# How to display a featured image in the list of entries

Tags: templating, assets, image

I created a field which uploads an image, and I want it to display it for each of my entries inside my for loop.

What's the code I should use to do it?

Comment: Is the image a field used only with one entry? Or is it a different image added to each of the entries in your loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for element in elements %}
    {% set asset = element.assetFieldHandle.one() %}
    {% if asset is not null %}
        <img src="{{ asset.getUrl()">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Take a look at [ElementQueries](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/) and [how to handle errors](https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms#defensive-coding-in-twig)